# How to inherit matplotlib in python?

Tags: python, inheritance, matplotlib

When I run the program below:

```
import matplotlib
class abc(matplotlib):
    def anything(self):
        print("anything")

aa=abc()
```

I got the following errors:

> File "test.py", line 2, in 
>       class abc(matplotlib): TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
>       module.**init**() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

How can I fix it?

Comment: Why would you try to inherit from a module? What are you trying to do? The reason for the error will be that matplotlib is an module instance and not a class anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`matplotlib` is a module/package.  You can't inherit from it since it isn't a class.

The closest thing that I can think of that you *could* do is something akin to:

```
# my_matplotlib.py
from matplotlib import *
import matplotlib

def plot(*args, **kwargs):
    """Overrides matplotlib.plot"""
    print "Hey Dude.  I'm plotting now!"
    return matplotlib.plot(*args, **kwargs)
```

Note that I really don't recommend doing this ...